# Find the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)(x-b)$.

Tags: polynomials

Q: Let $P(x)$ by a polynomial leaving remainder A when divided by $(x-a)$, and remainder B when divided by $(x-b)$, where $a$ does not equal $b$.

Find the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)(x-b)$.

A: $(\frac{A-B}{a-b})(\frac{Ba-Ab}{a-b})$

My working so far:

$P(a)=A=(a-b)G(x)+B)$

$P(b)=B=(b-a)Q(x)+A)$

$\frac{A-B}{a-b}=\frac{(B-A)G(x)}{(b-a)Q(x)}$

But I can't work out how to get rid of the G(x) and Q(x) or what to do next

Comment: When you divide $P(x)$ by a quadratic polynomial, the remainder $R(x)$ you get is a polynomial of degree at most $1$ (i.e. a constant or a linear polynomial). Furthermore, $R(a) = P(a) = A$ and $R(b) = P(b) = B$.

Comment: You can ignore $G$ and $Q$.  Use the facts that $P(a) = A$ and $P(b) = B$.  Then $P(x) = (x-a)(x-b)H(x) + R(x)$.  As achille hui writes, $R(x)$ must be linear, and you know $R(a)=A$ and $R(b)=B$.  So you have two equations in two unknowns to solve.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1925242/321264.

Answer (score 1):

The remainder you are looking for is of the form $ux + v$ for some $u$ and $v$.
Now $$ P(a) = ua+v$$ and $$P(b) = ub+v $$ so $u = \frac{P(a)-P(b)}{a-b}$ and $v = P(a) - a \frac{P(a)-P(b)}{a-b}$